# Is there a way get app detail version from google play with special devices

Tags: android, google-play

[the app detail of facebook](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E6w5y.png)

I visit [https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.facebook.katana&hl=en,](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.facebook.katana&hl=en) ,  and  want find the latest version of the app. But the version show is  "Varies with device"。 I try to use 42matters.com api but the version is same.

How can i get the version with special devise from google play ?